# Freescale MCP8260, don't understand pins

Tags: embedded, clock, pins, freescale

I am looking at the [Freescale MCP8260 processor](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=MPC8260).

For programming PINS you set values to some registers. I would like to use MII interface for Fast Ethernet for example. I can see the Dedicated PINS table and everything is fine. But TX_CLK and RX_CLK aren't at the table. Why are they missing? All other PINS exist (except from 2 that manual explains but says nothing why the clock pins aren't there).
However there is a register that can be used to change the clock but why are they missing?

Is it possible A TDMA device to use the same clock for receiving and transmitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify which clocks are used for TX and RX in the CPM Multiplexing logic (Chapter 16 in the databook).